# Numpy pack bits into 32-bit little-endian values

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, bit-manipulation, endianness

Numpy provides [packbits](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.packbits.html) function to convert from values to individual bits. With `bitorder='little'` I can read them in C as uint8_t values without issues. However, I would like to read them as uint32_t values. This means that I have to reverse the order of each 4 bytes.
I tried to use

```
import numpy as np

array = np.array([1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1, 
   1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1])
array = np.packbits(array, bitorder='little')
array.dtype = np.uint32
array.byteswap(inplace=True)

print(array)
```

but have the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sample.py", line 5, in <module>
    array.dtype = np.uint32
ValueError: When changing to a larger dtype, its size must be a divisor of the total size in bytes of the last axis of the array.
```

I have 50 bits in the input. The first chunk of 32 bits written in the little-endian format (earliest input bit is the least significant bit) are `0b10101001101011001101001010101101 = 2846675629`, the second is `0b100111001101011001 = 160601`. So the expected output is

```
[2846675629 160601]
```

Comment: Please, provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example),

Comment: @Curious In the future, please provide *full* error stack trace, not just the bottom line. It will help people help you much faster, and will greatly reduce the chance of your questions getting closed. Also include expected output.

Comment: What is the output you *expect*?

Comment: Also note that from the `packbits` doc: "Array of type uint8 whose elements represent bits corresponding to the logical (0 or nonzero) value of the input elements. The shape of packed has the same number of dimensions as the input (unless axis is None, in which case the output is 1-D)." - Returns a uint8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[My first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67456854/913098) fixes the exception.

This answer, relies on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49791312/numpy-packbits-pack-to-uint16-array) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36534035/pad-0s-of-numpy-array-to-nearest-power-of-two/36534077)

- Pad the array from the right to the nearest power of 2
- Reshape to have some arrays, each array of size 32
- Pack bits PER ARRAY and only then view as `unit32`.

```
import numpy as np
import math


# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49791312/numpy-packbits-pack-to-uint16-array
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36534035/pad-0s-of-numpy-array-to-nearest-power-of-two/36534077


def next_power_of_2(number):
    # Returns next power of two following 'number'
    return 2**math.ceil(math.log(number, 2))


a = np.array([
    1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,
    1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1
])

# a = np.array([
#     0 for _ in range(31)
# ] + [1])
padding_size = next_power_of_2(len(a)) - len(a)
b = np.concatenate([a, np.zeros(padding_size)])
c = b.reshape((-1, 32)).astype(np.uint8)
d = np.packbits(c, bitorder='little').view(np.uint32)

print(d)
```

output:

> [2846675629     160601]

Comment: Thanks, it works! It seems we don't need to pad to the next power of two, just to the 32 bits, right?

Comment: @Curious that's right. I guess I overdid it.

Answer (score -1):

You can't use `array.dtype = np.uint32` as you did, because numpy arrays have to be consecutive in memory.

Instead, you can create a new array of the new type.

```
import numpy as np

array = np.array([1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1])
array = np.packbits(array, bitorder='little')
array = np.array(array, dtype=np.uint32)
array.byteswap(inplace=True)

print(array)
```

Comment: I expect the output array to contain only 2 values (64 bits total) since I have 50 input bits. However, your code produces 7 values: `[2902458368 3523215360 2885681152 2835349504 1493172224 1929379840 33554432]`

Comment: Please edit your question. It is not reproducible as it is now.

Comment: What exactly is not reproducible? I didn't get that. Do you mean the original question (I can run it with `python sample.py` with installed numpy) or my previous comment on your answer?

Comment: By [mre] I mean: 1. Exact expected output 2. full error trace 3. MINIMAL - can you reprocude this on something much simpler to understand than 50 bits?

Comment: I added expected output in the question